# How to move each li up using hover and padding

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to make each li go up by a few pixels when users hover but it seems like my math and css skills are not helping. As you can see for now, every li is moving up at the same time. I appreciate if anyone provide me a quick trick or even a better way to achieve this.

Thank you.

```css
    nav ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:1rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-weight:300;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size:1.5rem;
    }

    nav ul li {
      margin:0 1rem;
      display:inline-block;
      cursor:pointer;
      padding:10px 20px;
    }
    
    
    nav ul li:hover {
      padding:15px 20px 15px;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>About</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i>Portfolio</li>
      <li><i class="far fa-file"></i>Resume</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `display:inline-block` that's why on hover all `li` moving, so you need to use `float:left` and set height for `li`

```css
*,:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:1rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-weight:300;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size:1.5rem;
      list-style-type:none;
    }

    nav ul li {
      margin:0 1rem;
      float:left;
      cursor:pointer;
      padding:10px 20px;
      height:50px;
      transition: all .2s linear;
    }
    
    
    nav ul li:hover {
      padding:15px 20px 15px;
      height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>About</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i>Portfolio</li>
      <li><i class="far fa-file"></i>Resume</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't touched CSS for a week and that does make me forget a lot of stuff haha.

Comment: @YongJunJung Welcome Mate

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Used vertical-align: top;

Heres the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nys1e4k8/

```
nav ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:1rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight:300;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:1.5rem;
}

nav ul li {
  margin:0 1rem;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


nav ul li:hover {
  padding: 6px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question, how does vertical-align:top help this work? And why are padding set differently (6px and 0px) from (10px)?